# Git workflow: commit != OS save

Tags: git, testing, edit

I am unclear on how git is supposed to work. I have looked at the official docs, and many tutorials, but I have not seen an answer to this question.

When you have a new feature or bug fix you want to work on, and you create a branch for that purpose,  what are you supposed to do with the interim files while your work is in progress? Git is only saving 'snapshots' of various versions of your working files. But in order to see if any of your edits work or are worth keeping, you have to test them. And you can't test them without them being saved to the disk by the operating system. Once you have saved these files, they are not 'snapshots', so how does git save or restore anything to the original condition of master once the files on disk have been 'permanently' saved in order to be run and tested?

There must be an answer, but I haven't found it. The only tutorial I have found that even references saving by the OS was http://ryanflorence.com/git-for-beginners/, and that only in reference to a merge conflict.

Comment: Git is not responsible for handling with the particular tools you're using. That is your responsibility. Any intermediate files that you don't want saved should be specified in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Why do you think commit != OS save? Every commit is saved in the .git folder.

Comment: Saving a modification to a file in the working directory is the *least* permanent thing you can do in a git project. You can undo that change and save again, and the intermediate version is gone if you didn't commit it. Committing is what *makes* things permanent - you really have to go out of your way to convince git to completely delete a committed version of a file.

Comment: I think your mental model is confused. The workflow is (1) Save your files to the OS. (2) Commit them, which copies them to the database. (3) If you want to go back to an earlier version, restore them from the database.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I am definitely confused, that's why I posted. By 'database' I assume you mean git? Let's say I start work on a new feature in a new branch which requires modifying some files critical to the app in its original state. Then I decide the new feature is a flop and will not be merged. But my critical files have been overwritten in order to commit, or save, the new feature and test it. Git is going to restore the original files to their original condition even though git is not the os? What if I discard the branch? Are those modified files going to stay on my disk or be replaced?

Comment: Git is a database. When you commit, you save your changes into the database. If you decide the feature is a flop, you tell git to restore your files from the database to the version that existed before you made your changes. Git is just a fancy backup system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be conflating a commit with a hard-disk save.  You can't commit that which already isn't saved, which is true in any VCS; you can't version something that hasn't been written to a file yet.

Git actually considers what's been changed as a [snapshot](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), in the sense that you start with an initial file which may be large, but Git will only ever bother keeping track of changes to it that happened between versions.  If part of a file is touched, then only that part of the file is updated.

Here's a sample from [a repository I'm working on](https://github.com/MakotoTheKnight/codeschool-intellij/blame/11d1a66e992bceae907c41dc1cdddc81eec5faf5/build.gradle).  I'm using IntelliJ, so the bold SHAs are the most recent change.

[image]

If I wanted to move the file back to a specific point, I could. Notice that also, there are a lot of things that haven't changed since November '14 (and a few changes exist since May), but there are definite changes since then. This is what's meant when snapshots are being kept as opposed to entire versions of files.  If I wanted to reintroduce the version of the file as it was in May '14, I'd need to instruct Git to check out 5c5f896b.

The end result that you see is the entire file as it is at that instant.  This means that it could be an amalgam of all of your commits over the last few months (or years).  It is *still* a snapshot because it will only ever consider the most recent changes to that file.

> ...Git thinks of its data more like a set of snapshots of a miniature filesystem. Every time you commit, or save the state of your project in Git, it basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment and stores a reference to that snapshot. To be efficient, if files have not changed, Git doesn’t store the file again, just a link to the previous identical file it has already stored. Git thinks about its data more like a stream of snapshots.

The more you get into Git, you'll discover that this approach allows it to go back to "known working states", or keep multiple versions of the same code in the same repository.  For the most part, you would discover this [with a bit of reading](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and some [hands-on exercises](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).

Comment: "If part of a file is touched, then only that part of the file is updated." Sorry, this is not right. It's svn, not git. In this case, git will create a new file, so we have 2 blobs in git terms.

Comment: @Kata: but in practice, git will use deltas internally to reduce duplication.

Comment: @Makoto: Actually, I am trying to unconflate. It was when I realized that commits were not saves that I posted. I did not realize I could not commit something that was not already saved, so thanks for that bit of enlightenment. So even though a file has been overwritten, saved, and committed, if I decide to throw that branch away git will restore the file to its original condition so I can start over? This is where I got confused, I didn't see how that was supposed to happen when the original was no longer in that condition on my disk. I've read a lot, as I said, but the exercises should help.

Comment: Git is keeping track of the state of the file itself internally.  You can read all of the gory details of that [in the Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) chapter.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to stopped responding at the 12th step... sigh... Still, I clicked through the rest of the steps and even that does not explicitly explain the workflow and difference between saving via the OS and a commits. What I plan to do now is my own test tutorial where I will try to restore the original after overwriting it as part of the branching process. I want to see what happens to the overwritten version as well as the original master.

Comment: git internals is what I needed.